# Estimating distribution given top k order statistics and unknown n

Tags: estimation, order-statistics

This problem occurred to me a couple of days ago, in the context of a game with a leaderboard.  I wondered, given only the leaderboard, could I estimate parameters for the distribution of scores?

Estimation of order statistics is a reasonably well understood problem, but as far as I can see all require knowledge of n, the total number of games giving rise to the leaderboard.

If we know properties of the order statistics (for example, if we know that they tend to a uniform distribution) we might estimate the parameters of the order statistics distribution and work back from there.  However, this feels rather unsatisfying.

Comment: You could substitute a prior probability distribution on $n$ for knowing $n$.

Comment: And to clarify, are you saying you've got the top $k$ scores out of unknown $n$ from a known family (e.g. log-normal) whose parameters (e.g $\mu$, $\sigma$) you want to estimate? So the trouble comes from having a nuisance parameter to deal with? Reliability statistics deals with these sort of problems; exponential order statistic models especially.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I should make clear this isn't an urgent practical problem I have - I just didn't have an answer and neither did my colleagues, and Googling did not get me very far.